# WinForms BindingSource PositionChanged event raised two times

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my project:

In a project create a new form. then create two buttons and a bindingsource.

for button1 write this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();
    lst.Add(1);
    lst.Add(3);
    lst.Add(3);

    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = lst;
}
```

for button2 write this code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = null;
}
```

then add a PositionChanged event for the bindingsource and write this code:

```
private void bindingSource1_PositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
}
```

Run the application and press button1. In button1 we set the `DataSource` to the list and the `PositionChanged` is fired normally. Thats OK.

Then press button2. We simply set the `DataSource` to null. But it shows two messages. You see that the `PositionChanged` event is fired two times.

It alse occurs if you write `this.bindingSource1.Clear();` too.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "why" would be by examining the source code for the [BindingSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingSource.cs,3ae01e7a16f36ff8) class.

It just looks like clearing or setting the DataSource to null makes multiple calls to raise the PositionChanged event.  To avoid it in your code, simply unhook the event before clearing the DataSource, then rewire the event again:

```
bindingSource1.PositionChanged -= bindingSource1_PositionChanged;
bindingSource1.DataSource = null;
bindingSource1.PositionChanged += bindingSource1_PositionChanged;
```